# Storing exact same decimal points in MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a column name `cost` which has `decimal(20,8)` data type and when I try to insert data it appends extra `000s`.

i.e. if I insert `10.11` while inserting it gets stored as `10.11000000`

What I want to do is insert only inserted decimal points whether it is 10.11 then store it as it is and if it is 10.0012 then store it as it.

How can I achieve this with MySql and NodeJS?

I have seen `cast()` and other functions but I don't want it to be at the query level.

Is there anything can be done at table or DB structure side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'it appends extra 000s.' - odd way of looking at it as you have defined the column as having 8 decimal places do you want somehow to suppress all the zeros when displaying?

Comment: Yes, While storing value I don't want to append extra 0s. Only whatsoever added decimal points have to be stored

Comment: In that case store as varchar (you won't be able to do arithmetic so easily though)

Comment: @P.Salmon Let's hope if I find something useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you cannot and I will explain why below:

You have set a data type of `decimal(20,8)` for this particular column. Therefore looking at it from a binary perspective, this column will store 20 bits before the . and 8 bits after it. All the data you will enter will have that particular length. The reason why the value is not as `000000000010.11000000` value is because zeros are never shown before a digit, however if we had to look at the bits the value takes up in memory, that would be its value. A data type of `decimal(20,8)` can take the following range of numbers in all; from: `-999999999999.99999999` to `999999999999.99999999`meaning that you can have 20 digits in total, 8 of which are after the decimal point.

Recapitulating, the value in the database will always be saved in that format. If you wish to amend the front end to remove the trailing zeros, you would need to do that from node.js.

Comment: Just to clarify `DECIMAL(20,8)` means that you can have 20 digits *in total* and 8 after the decimal point. So the range for that would be -999999999999.99999999 to 999999999999.99999999 i.e 12 for numbers before the decimal point and 8 after.

Comment: thanks @slaakso forgot the negatives there. I updated my answer for the sake of clarity and future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the value in database is a different thing than the formatting used when the value is displayed. When you have a column with datype `decimal(20,8)`, it will allow up to 8 decimals. When you store value 10.11, 10.110, 10.1100 or 10.11000000, they are all saved as same 10.11 value.

When you read out the value from database (commmand line client, any appplication) that application determines how to show the value. For example, the commmand line client chooses to show all the decimals.

Comment: OP has stated 'I have seen cast() and other functions but I don't want it to be at the query level.'

Comment: @P.Salmon. So? The question was why MySQL stored extra decimals. It does not. The extra decimals are just formatting done when applications displays the data. Storing numeric data as varchar is a bad advise.

Comment: @slaakso but I can even see added extra 0s in MySQL table as well

Comment: @MysteriousCoder What application are you using to look at the MySQL table? MySQL client / MySQL Workbench / something else?

Comment: @slaakso phpmyadmin

Comment: @MysteriousCoder. phpmyadmin is just formatting the displayes data based on the column definition. It is just coded to do that. It could as well display the data without the all the decimals. It has nothing to do how the value is stored in the database.

Comment: @slaakso so is there any way ?

Comment: @slaakso,  that'tl be the so then

Comment: @ MysteriousCoder. You really do not have any problem there. When you create your own application, you can choose the formatting for your columns. If you want to change the behavior of phpmyadmin, you need to change the code. But as said, this really should not be an issue.

Comment: @MysteriousCoder. You can use datatype `real` which has no fixed number of decimals so phpmyadmin will show the decimals you enter. Note though that using `decimal` is usually better than `real` as you tend to get rounding errors with `real`.

Comment: @slaakso it is banking application so there is hell lot of calclution in my project

Comment: Just use `DECIMAL` and do not worry about phpmyadmin. You can choose your own formatting.